# C++ .lib file required for CLR dll but not for non-CLR

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli, .lib

In a simple test project, I have two C++ compiled dlls

**NonClrDll:** A regular C++ dll (non `/clr`)

**Wrapper:** A `/clr` compiled dll that is only unmanaged (native) code for now

To use the NonClrDll in a C++ client project, all I have to do is include a reference to the dll project and the appropriate header code ([as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)). However, to use the `/clr` compiled wrapper dll, I have to also add the .lib file as an additional dependency ([as described here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Compiler/Linker/Libraries/Configuring_Visual_Studio)). My questions are...

1. Why do I not need to include a .lib file for the NonClrDll? I was assuming that the project reference took care of this. Does it?
2. If the project reference is supposed to take care of this, why do I need to add the additional .lib file dependency for the `/clr` compiled wrapper?

Comment: "include a reference to the dll project" does only one thing, it tells the linker to also link the .lib file that the project generates.  A /clr project does not normally generate a useful .lib file since the metadata in the assembly is enough to bind at runtime.  You are using it off-label, change the Linker > General > Ignore Import Libraries setting.

Comment: @HansPassant Yep, that was the issue, same as Jack posted below. I guess that makes sense since `/clr` isn't usually referenced by a native app. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is because the C++/CLI Project has the linker setting "IgnoreImportLibrary" defaulted to "Yes" and the native C++ Project it is defaulted to "No".